# Performance differs a lot on two Windows machine

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have a Java application developed in Eclipse. It's multi-threading. I tested on two Windows 10 from the same manufacturer. JVM settings are the same in Eclipse. JVM arguments are using default settings in both machines. JDK are the same, 1.8.

What's strange is that on one machine, the multi-threading mode runs 50% faster than the single-threading mode. However, on the other machine, the multi-threading effect is very minimal, without speedup.

What might cause this?

EDIT:

I discovered the problem. One machine has only 2 cores and the other one has 4 cores and that makes a big difference!

Comment: dumb question, but same amount of cores correct?

Comment: I'm guessing one machine's cpu has more threads than another

Comment: Are the machines of the same model? How did you even measure the performance?

Comment: @marstran, as i said, I measure by running time to process the task.

Comment: @Jason, yes. As a matter of fact, the machine which runs much faster has only 8G memory, while the other has 16G.

Comment: unexpected. but that is very interesting!

Comment: @Jason, different number of cores. actually!

Comment: To measure the performance accurately, you need to do an actual benchmark. Just checking the running time of the process won't be accurate.